# Rails: ActiveRecord scope based on property of child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, named-scope

I have three models `Component`, `Version` and `User` which are associated with each other like so:

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :versions, class_name 'ComponentVersion'
end

class ComponentVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :component
    belongs_to :approver, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I want to create two scopes on `Component`: **`approved`** and **`unapproved`**. A Component is 'approved' when it has at least one approved `version`, and a version is approved when its `approver_id` is not `nil`. So `Component.approved` should return all approved components and `Component.unapproved` should return all unapproved versions.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this.

I can define scopes on ComponentVersion easily enough:

```
class ComponentVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :component
    belongs_to :approver, class_name: 'User'
    scope :approved,   -> { where('approver_id IS NOT NULL') }
    scope :unapproved, -> { where('approver_id IS NULL') }
end
```

Then at the console `Component.joins(:version).merge(ComponentVersion.approved)` gives me something close to what I'd want for `Component.approved`, except it includes duplicates (if a Component has more than one approved version, it gets returned more than once.)

And `Component.joins(:version).merge(ComponentVersion.unapproved)` is no good for the opposite because it returns Components which have both unapproved and approved versions, when I only want Components which *only* have unapproved Versions (or no Versions at all).

I've also tried passing SQL queries to `joins` that include `OUTER JOIN` instead of INNER but they're not giving me what I want, and they're stretching my limited understanding of SQL.

How can I get the queries I need?

(I'm using Postgres and Rails 3.2.13, in case it matters.)

Answer (score 3):

It seems impossible to get what you want using query generator DSL. I usually use correlated subqueries for this.

```
class Component
  scope :approved, lambda{ where('EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM component_versions WHERE component_versions.component_id = components.id AND component_versions.approver_id IS NOT NULL)') }
end
```

Another version

```
class Component
  scope :approved, lambda { where('id IN (SELECT c.id FROM components c JOIN component_versions cv ON c.id = cv.component_id AND cv.approver_id IS NOT NULL)' }
end
```

With Postgres it probably doesn't matter which one you'll use, it has a pretty good query planner.

Comment: Works a charm! Although the second example is missing a closing `)`. But how can I define the `unapproved` scope?

Comment: Use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`. It seems that PostgreSQL optimizer is not as good as I thought so stick with second version. As a bonus, it's easier to understand. Btw, you should really consider learning a bit of SQL, with subqueries you'll be ready to tackle like 98% of DB access tasks arising in web dev.